# Присвоить значения списка 1 списку 2 но с удаленным первым элементом

Tags: c#

```
List<string> path = new List<string>() { "первый","второй" });
List<string> path1 = path.RemoveAt(0);
```

Вот так, к сожалению, не сработает. Как сделать что бы сработало?

Comment: Скопируйте полностью, а потом в копии удалите первый элемент.

Comment: `path1 = path.Skip(1).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
List<string> path = new List<string>() { "первый","второй" });
List<string> path1 = path.GetRange(1, path.Count - 1);
```